# for-each-object inside for-each-object

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I'm writing loop inside loop and use main loop variable into child loop array variable.

input parameters

```
param(
[array]$Emp_ID=@(1,2),
[array]$Emp_Name=@("Scott", "Jones")
)

$Sql_Get_Emp_ID_List = @()
    $Emp_ID | ForEach-Object { $Src_Emp_ID = $_
    $Emp_Name | ForEach-Object { $Src_Emp_Name = $_

    $Query_GetDeptID="(Select Dept_ID From Dept_Table Where Emp_Name = '$Src_Emp_Name' And Emp_ID = $Src_Emp_ID)"        
    }
    }
```

I'm getting 4 cross join sql statements out of above for-each-object loop. below are the statements but I want to get only 2 statements.

```
Select Dept_ID From Dept_Table Where Emp_Name = 'Scott' And Emp_ID = 1
Select Dept_ID From Dept_Table Where Emp_Name = 'Scott' And Emp_ID = 2
Select Dept_ID From Dept_Table Where Emp_Name = 'Jones' And Emp_ID = 1
Select Dept_ID From Dept_Table Where Emp_Name = 'Jones' And Emp_ID = 2
```

I want get output like this:

```
Select Dept_ID From Dept_Table Where Emp_Name = 'Scott' And Emp_ID = 1
Select Dept_ID From Dept_Table Where Emp_Name = 'Jones' And Emp_ID = 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to iterate over two equal length arrays, you can use one `Foreach-Object` and one index for both arrays.

```
$emp_id = 1,2
$emp_name = 'scott','jones'
$query = "Select Dept_ID From Dept_Table Where Emp_Name = '{0}' And Emp_ID = {1}"

0..($emp_id.Count-1) | Foreach-Object { $query -f $emp_name[$_],$emp_id[$_] }
```

**Explanation:**

`$emp_id.Count` returns the number of items (2) in the `$emp_id` array. Since indexes start at 0, you will only need indexes `[0]` and `[1]` here. `$query` is your query string with placeholders `{0}` and `{1}` for the [string format operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html) (`-f`). Then the `Foreach-Object` creates a query for each index substituting one element (the same element) from each array.

Comment: It is inside of a `foreach-object`.